# Is it legal to market a product as DLNA enabled if it has not passed DLNA certification yet?

Tags: software, licensing

We would like to push our DLNA-enabled product to the market faster and receive feedback from customers before we go for various optional certifications, including DLNA certification (which also require more resources than our startup company currently has). DLNA standard itself is open and all the requirements are freely available, the same way as UPNP specifications which are the basis for DLNA.

Obviously, we cannot use the "DLNA certified" logo on our device yet.

But are we allowed to use "DLNA" logo or at least claim that the device supports DLNA at some level to encourage our customers to try out the feature and report any issues found, so we can fix them in our next software updates?

It would be great to have an advice from people who have used DLNA in their products and have clearly marketed their products as DLNA capable without having obtained DLNA certificates. Did it went smooth? Were there no objections from Digital Living Network Alliance against your product?

Here are relevant links:

[Digital Living Network Alliance](http://www.dlna.org/)

[DLNA certification guide and description](http://www.dlna.org/certification/certification/)

Comment: First of all; what **is** DLNA? Yiu shpuld include a lonk to either an official website or a reliable artocle that explains it. Now, does DLNA have something similar to "Pat. pending"? What exactly does certification entail; is it a mere rubber-stamp or a stringent examination?

Comment: I updated the question. Anyway, I guess only a person who has ever been dealing with releasing DLNA-enabled devices will be able to give an answer based on his/her experience, although it would be great (but unlikely) to hear from lawyers of Digital Living Network Alliance itself.

Comment: I don't think significant direct expertise will be needed if the guide and description or additional comments make do, but certainly knowledge about advertising law (viz. claiming to support standard despite lack of certification for it) and contract or commercial law (viz. trademarks, using certification names without consideration of actually getting the certification) would be a big help.

Comment: It may depend on jurisdiction, but it would seem reasonable to state "generally compatible with DNLA specification; certification pending" - using the DNLA logo may not be acceptable as I would imagine its owned by the certification body.